# Binary Subtraction Borrowing Logic for 1000 - 0110?

Tags: binary, bit, subtraction

I am having a hardtime understanding the borrowing logic for 1000 - 0110 . I know the answer would be 0010 but I am having trouble understanding the borrowing part a little.

First Step is Ok 0 - 0 = 0

```
1000
0110
----
   0
```

Second Step 0 - 1 , so we need to borrow . We borrow 1 and as result 10 - 1 = 1

```
   ->1
    1000
    0110
    ----
      10
```

But at the next step there is nothing to borrow, so how does it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you borrow, you carry over binary 10 to the lower bit, so:

```
  0
->1
 0000
 0110
 ----
    0
```

Then you borrow again, and subtract 1 from 10, which is 1:

```
   0
->11
 0000
 0110
 ----
    0
```

And finally:

```
   0
->11
 0000
 0110
 ----
 0010
```

Comment: In the second step , the borrow again step is where the cofusion lies. When we are again borrowing , shouldn't it become 0 instead of 1 like it happened for first borrow .

Comment: @May13ank There is a difference between the first and te second borrow.   With the first, you are borrowing from 1, and 1 - 1 = 0.  When carrying over, you carry over a value equal to the base. In this case, the base is 2, so you carry over 2, or 10 in binary. So with the second case, you borrow from 10, and 10 - 1 = 1 (in binary).

Answer (score 0):

In computer, number will be presented as 2 parts: sign bit and value bits. a - b will be performed as a + (-b)

for positive number, its sign part is 0, value part is its binary representation. For your case, it's:    0 1000

for negative number, its sign part is 1, value part is: ~number + 1, for 0110, ~a is 1001, +1, the representation is : 1 1010

0   1000

1   1010

=======

0   0010

it is positive number 2